# Parentheses don't work in Bash script

Tags: bash, syntax, parentheses

I'm writing a script that needs to erase everything from a directory except two directories, mysql and temp.

I asked a question earlier and got this code that works in the command line:

```
rm -rf !(mysql|temp)
```

However it doesn't work in the script. I get this error "Syntax error: "(" unexpected".

Is there something special about parentheses I need to do?

Comment: Are you running the script with `bash` or `sh`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to explicitly enable extended patterns in your script:

```
shopt -s extglob
```